# GCovr does not generate a valid report for c++ project build by scons

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov

I am tring to generate coverage report by gcovr. But got invalid report or 0% coverage report
My project structure look like.

Myproject:

```
 src-----where my all source files stored
 testCases---Where my all source files stored
 RunTestCases--From where I run my testCases
```

First I build src by scons from src directory.

Then I build TestCases from testCases directory by scons

Then I run test cases form RunTestCases directory

Last I generated coverage report for source file from src directory

Everthings is ok. My test Cases got pass but coverage report is 0%

I used below command to generated coverage report

gcovr -r . -e "include.*" --html --html-details -o $result_dir/result.html

Please help me..

Comment: And all your source code is compiled and linked with the `--coverage` flag ?

Comment: All source code is compiled with --coverage flag(i.e -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs). But I don't know about link.. Would you please explained what does link means?